# Create class object with let or var keyword?

Tags: ios, swift

As apple say [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82) "Classes Are Reference Types", means class objects are like pointer in other languages(C, C++, Objective-C) and we can change value of constant objects(let in swift).

Then which is preferred way for creating class object(Always create a constant object or create a variable object). As I create and test both are working in same manner then what is the difference of "let and var" in terms of class object.

```
class Student {
var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

When I create variable object of class Student.

```
var student = Student(name: "student name")
student.name = "Raj"

print("name = \(student.name)")
```

works as expacted, but when I create a constant object.

```
let student = Student(name: "studentName")
student.name = "Raj"

print("name = \(student.name)")
```

Both are able to change values, because they reference type which is ok. But want to know which is preferred way for creating class object and what are the differences between of them in terms of class objects.

Comment: You can't prefer the one over the other, because they are both used to achieve different results.

If you define the `name` property as a `let` instead of `var` you would see that you're unable to edit the name after object initialization.

Comment: Don't use the term "class object". That is used in languages like Objective-C where classes are themselves objects. What you are talking about are _instances_ of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't assign new object if you created Student object with let

```
let student2 = Student(name: "mohan")
let student = Student(name: "sohan")

student = student2 // gives you an error.
```

but if you created with var you can change the student object to another object and it pointed to the another object.

```
let student2 = Student(name: "mohan")
var student = Student(name: "sohan")

student = student2 // have ref  of student2
print(student.name) // gives you mohan

student.name = "rohan"

print(student.name) // rohan
print(student2.name) // rohan
```